# Flutter date picker issue

Tags: flutter

pubspec.yaml
added line

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.4.49

In main.dart file added code for calendar from below link,
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/example
getting below error when running the app.

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.50/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7596:37: Error: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.

- 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
  scrollableState: Scrollable.of(context),

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have a look at this issue....check you have the right versions of flutter and the package.: https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/732

Comment: this isn't about package. its about Null issue on ur ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart'). scrollable widgets.. show us your code snipshots

Answer (score 0):

Currently the debugger show the above mentioned error because you are trying to assign a value (`ScrollableState?`, the question mark at the end means it can be null) to a parameter that accepts only a non-null value (`ScrollableState`).

If you are sure that the parameter cannot be null, you can assign it with a `!` mark at the end.

e.g.

```
myWidget(
  state: myWidgetState! //using the "!" at the end
);
```